# image display and modal pop up based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script where I cycle though various images based on the radio button selection.  This works well and cycles through them all without issue.

My issue is that I would like to have a modal pop up for all of the images.  These image names change based on the item displayed, so I save the image names in an array (array of n size.

here is the radio code:

```
<ul>
<li class="radio-attribute">
<label for="2" class="radio-attribute">
<input type="radio" id="2" name="id[27]" value="175" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
<img src="images/blue_swatch.png" alt="GBM0911B Blue" title=" GBM0911B Blue " width="45" height="40" />
</label>
</li>

<li class="radio-attribute">
<label for="3" class="radio-attribute">
<input type="radio" id="3" name="id[27]" value="173" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
<img src="images/black_swatch.png" alt="GBM0911BK Black" title=" GBM0911BK Black " width="41" height="40" />
</label>
</li>

</ul>
```

These buttons work fine.

The javascript is as follows:

```
var images = ["GBM0911PL.png","GBM0911R.png"];
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("piGal");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    function change_image(radioID) {
        document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = "<img id=\"myImg\" src=\"images/"+ images[radioID] +"\" />";
    }

// Get the modal

    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

The modal tag is as follows:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('piGal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="piGal">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

I display the images like this:

```
    <div id="piGal" style="float: left;">

      <a href="images/GLAMOURFRONT.jpg"><img src="images/GLAMOURFRONT.jpg" alt="Glamour Bubble " title=" Glamour " width="225" height="184"  id="myImg"  /></a>    
</div>
```

And finally the css used for the modal:

```
 /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This is just a modal I copied from the site https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp
to get this started.

The modal though is not popping open at all, and I need it to pop open the selected image from the radio select.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your onclick event listener is set to only trigger when you click an item with the ID `#myImg`. You want the code to execute whenever you click each of your radio boxes, so I recommend looping through those radio buttons:

```
document.querySelectorAll('label.radio-attribute').forEach(function (radioClick) {
  radioClick.querySelector('img').addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    img.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  });
});
```

Essentially, this loops through every radio img and adds an event listener for click to it, which then sets the SRC of and shows your target image in the fullscreen view.

Comment: Thanks, almost, as soon as I click a radio selection now, the modal opens up immediately, verses having a mouse roll over click on the image, additionally the image in the modal is missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you could set up a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with some sample code, I'm confident I'd be more able to help with a misrendered view.

Comment: It's because you have two elements with `piGal` as their ID. Fix the div#piGal and img#piGal. I'd recommend #piGalImg for the ID on your IMG tag. Then, you could just have a `var galleryImage = document.querySelector("#piGalImg")`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
<a href="images/GLAMOURFRONT.jpg"></a>
```

I think this is preventing your image from triggering the modal.